# SDL mouse wheel not picking up

Tags: sdl, events, linux

Running Ubuntu 11.04, SDL 1.2 trying to pickup mouse wheel up/down movement with this (stripped down) code:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    SDL_MouseButtonEvent *mousebutton = NULL;

    while ( !done )
    {
        if(mousebutton != NULL && mousebutton->button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
            yrot += 0.75f;
        else if(mousebutton != NULL && mousebutton->button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
            yrot -= 0.75f;
        else if(mousebutton != NULL && mousebutton->button == SDL_BUTTON_WHEELUP){
            xrot += 0.75f;
        }else if(mousebutton != NULL && mousebutton->button == SDL_BUTTON_WHEELDOWN){
            xrot -= 0.75f;
        }

        while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            switch( event.type )
            {
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    mousebutton = &event.button; 
                    break;
                case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    mousebutton = NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
             }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

strange thing is, scrolling with the mouse button does nothing, but if I hold down a mouse button or two and then move the mouse it hits the SDL_BUTTON_WHEEL code occasionally.  This honestly reeks of a pointer issue, which would make sense since I've been spoiled with C# for the past couple years, but I am just not seeing it.

How do i correctly find mouse scroll events in SDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend going through these two tutorials:

- Event Driven Programming (SDL) http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson04/index.php
- Mouse Events(SDL) http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson09/index.php

If you still have problems after going through these tutorials, let me know - I'd be glad to help you out :)

Comment: Assassin: This code was hacked together from a NeHe tutorial, those LazyFoo tutorials, and some API documentation.  I will definitely go through those two tutorials again and see if it sheds some light, after work.

Comment: Aha! that was an insidious bug.  
For [mouse wheels] (www.libsdl.org/cgi/docwiki.cgi/SDL_MouseButtonEvent) it places two events into the event queue.  SDL_PollEvent reads until the queue is empty, so my code was hitting the inner loop twice, setting wheel button to null before i hit the yrot code.